bootstrap 5 click inside dropdown should not open close the dropdown
I have the following code


<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button <i class="bi bi-x inside-button"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
$('.inside-button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(new Date());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>



As you can see there is a bootstrap icon inside the button dropdown with a click event (by the class inside-button) the purpose of this functionality is to clear the content of the dropdown.
The problem is the dropdown still open and close when the icon is clicked, the click should only do the action without opening/closing the dropdown, how can I achieve this?
Note: I searched a lot inside stackoverflow before posting, this is for Bootstrap 5.

You could also try the split button dropdown in this case. The button could do the clearing, and the arrow button could be the normal dropdown.

Thanks to Tom's answer I was able to figure out the exact behavior I want.
The dropdown constructor he used pointed me to the right direction on how to control the show and hide behavior of a bootstrap dropdown.
After I needed to figure out how you check if a dropdown is already opened, according to the Bootstrap JS file, it checks the presence of the class show.
This also allow me to control the behavior when the dropdown is already opened.
This is the relevant code I wrote in the end:
// get the button toggle
let buttonToggle = $(this).closest('.dropdown-toggle');
// use the data property (bs-toggle) to get the class of the dropdown target element
let mainDropdown = $(this).closest('.' + buttonToggle.data('bs-toggle'));
// check if the toggle has the show class and use the dropdown method to hide or show the dropdown
if (buttonToggle.hasClass('show')) { mainDropdown.dropdown('hide'); } else { mainDropdown.dropdown('show'); }

Full code:


<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button <i class="bi bi-x inside-button"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
$('.inside-button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(new Date());
    let buttonToggle = $(this).closest('.dropdown-toggle');
    let mainDropdown = $(this).closest('.' + buttonToggle.data('bs-toggle'));
    if (buttonToggle.hasClass('show')) { mainDropdown.dropdown('hide'); } else { mainDropdown.dropdown('show'); }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>




this doesn't seem to be a good solution: what happens here is on click BS will open the dropdown first, and then clicking on the inside button will make BS close it, so the if block will never be truthy, and else block actually opens the dropdown, so the logic is actually reversed.. also double toggling has an impact on performace

You could hide the dropdown when you click on your inside-button :
new bootstrap.Dropdown(".dropdown-toggle").hide();



$('.inside-button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(new Date());
    new bootstrap.Dropdown(".dropdown-toggle").hide();
});
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button <i class="bi bi-x inside-button"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




thank you very much for your answer! It pointed me to the right direction, I wrote an answer with my full solution. I upvoted your answer.

The easiest way would probably be to move icon element out of the button, so that it doesn't trigger dropdown, and also stop click propagation from inside-button click (i.e. prevent triggering closing dropdown from outside), and then style icon with css so that it aligns with the button text and dropdown.
The alternative would be to add a lot of JS listeners, which would conditionally trigger dropdown, which is not a good solution.
Here's a quick-and-dirty example, which

moves icon out of button as a sibling
adds flex display to their container and centers them
moves icon left to appear inside button
moves button text to span to allow adjusting
adds e.stopPropagation(); to prevent dropdown close

 <div class="dropdown" style="
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
    <span style="
    padding-right: 20px;
    ">Dropdown button</span></button>
    <i class="bi bi-x inside-button" style="
    margin-left: -43px;
    color: var(--bs-white);

"></i>

$('.inside-button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

demo:


<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown" style="
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
    <span style="
    padding-right: 20px;
    ">Dropdown button</span></button>
    <i class="bi bi-x inside-button" style="
    margin-left: -43px;
    color: var(--bs-white);

"></i>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.inside-button').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(new Date());
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>




thanks for your answer! I understand your method but to be honest I am not a fan of adding extra css properties (as in your case to change the position of the x). Thanks to Tom's answer I was able to write the code I wanted. upvoted because your solution is valid in the end.

I think using css is the best approach when having nested listeners, otherwise it needs a lot of JS, which gets messy real quick..
